# EF 6 : Collection length decreased when i mark elements as deleted

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am trying to familiarize with EF 6 (Code First), WPF, and C#. I used two entities related with one-to-many relationship
« Simulation » is the parent
« echeance » is the child

```
public partial class simulation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

        public long SimulationId { get; set; }

       ...
       ...
       ...

        public virtual ICollection<Echeance> echeancier { get; set; }
        public List<Echeance> echeancierCopy { get; set; }
        ...
        ...
    ...
}


public partial class Echeance : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public long EcheanceId { get; set; }
    public long SimulationId { get; set; }
    public virtual simulation simulation { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Actually, when i want to modify a « simulation », first  i read it from database and i clone « echeancier » collection to « echeanceCopy » List and i  databind « echeanceCopy » to a WPF datagrid, so i can make changes interactively in datagrid cells. When i want to save simulation :
There are 2 cases :

1)  New simulation :  I make a tranfert of « echeanceCopy » Lits  to « echeancier »  collection andi saveit. It works fine.

2)  Old simulation :   I make a tranfert of « echeanceCopy » Lits  to « echeancier »  collection andi save it. 
If  « echeanceCopy » have a lenght less than « echeancier » then i have to mark as deleted elements present in « echeancier » and  not in  « echeanceCopy ». The problem that when i do this, the length of « echeancier » collection decreases automatically (i used debugger step by step) and i don’t  understand why ?.

here the code of transfert between collection and list

```
private void TransfertToOriginal(simulation item)
    {
        item.echeancierCopy.OrderBy(e => e.EchNumber);
        item.echeancier.OrderBy(e => e.EchNumber);

        int copylen     = item.echeancierCopy.Count();  
        int origlen     = item.echeancier.Count();                  
        try
       {
             if (copylen > origlen)
                for (int ii = 0; ii <= copylen - 1; ii++)
                    {
                       if (ii < origlen) //Copy and mark as Modified
                        EcheanceCopy(item, ii);
                        else //Add the new echeance and mark it as added
                    if (ii >= origlen)
                          {
                            item.echeancier.Add(item.echeancierCopy[ii]);
           base.GetCurrentUoW().RegisterNew<Echeance>(item.echeancier.ElementAt(ii));
                       }
                else
                {
                    if (copylen < origlen)
                    {
                        for (int ii = 0; ii < origlen; ii++)
                        {
                            if (ii < copylen)
                            {
                                EcheanceCopy(item, ii);
                            }
                            else //the echeance is deleted then mark it as deleted 
                            {
    //the following line will cause length of "echeancier" collection to decrease  
   //automatically each time in loop and fire an exception when ii become > length of 
   //"echeancier" ... exception says : index out of limit


      base.GetCurrentUoW().RegisterDeleted<Echeance>(item.echeancier.ElementAt(ii));
                        }
                    }
                  }
             }
           catch (Exception ex)
              {
                _logger.LogException(ex);
                throw ex;
              }

    }



  //Method for copy echeanceCopy-> echeancier
  private void EcheanceCopy(simulation item, int index)
    {
        item.echeancier.ElementAt(index).DateEcheance =    item.echeancierCopy[index].DateEcheance;
        item.echeancier.ElementAt(index).MontantPrincipal = item.echeancierCopy[index].MontantPrincipal;
        item.echeancier.ElementAt(index).MontantInteret = item.echeancierCopy[index].MontantInteret;
        item.echeancier.ElementAt(index).MontantTTC = item.echeancierCopy[index].MontantTTC;
        item.echeancier.ElementAt(index).MontantHT = item.echeancierCopy[index].MontantHT;
        item.echeancier.ElementAt(index).MontantTVA = item.echeancierCopy[index].MontantTVA;
        base.GetCurrentUoW().RegisterChanged<Echeance>(item.echeancier.ElementAt(index));
    }
```

Sorry i forget the code of Unit of work

```
  //Mark entity as deleted
    public void RegisterDeleted<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
        base.Entry<T>(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;

    }


//Mark entity as Modified
public void RegisterChanged<T>(T item) where T : class
    {

        base.Entry<T>(item).State = EntityState.Modified;

    }


//Mark entity as Added
  public void RegisterNew<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
                base.Entry<T>(item).State = EntityState.Added;

    }
```

Here the code for save in database

```
public override void Modify(simulation item)
    {


        //If we are in Edit mode
         try
         {
             if (item.SimulationId != 0)
             {
                 //Detach the working collection from dbcontext
                 DetachEcheancier(item.echeancierCopy.ToList());

                 //Transfert the working collection to original collection 
                 TransfertToOriginal(item);
             }

             else  //New Simulation
             {
                 //Copy all working collection elements to original collection
                 item.echeancier = new List<Echeance>(item.echeancierCopy);
                 //Mark all elements of original collection as added
                 SetEcheancierAsAdded(item);
             }

             base.Modify(item); //Then save (call SaveChanges() from uow
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             _logger.LogException(ex);
             throw ex;
         }

    }
```

Comment: If you delete an element or mark it as deleted, it will be removed from the Collection (well it's deleted, eh?). But why are you even doing this all? If you do not want to save just don't call SaveChanges() DbContext is UnitOfWork already.

Comment: I want to save changes, so i used "TransfertToOriginal" Method to prepare "echeancier" collection to save it in database. Actually, i also used SaveChanges later but i don't mentioned it in my code. About your question, why  do i this ?  otherwise, How  can i save changes then ?

Comment: You say that if i mark an element of collection as deleted, it will be removed from this collection. Is this EF behavior normal ? if yes I don't Understand how EF will know records that it has to delete from database if they already are removed from the original collection ?

Comment: EF will take care of everything necessary for you - you don't have to wrap "add" and "change" and "remove". EF has an ChangeTracker, which will see, if you do something.

Comment: Thank you Grumbler85, It seems that i have a lot of work to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution. Actually i created three collections, one for deleted elements, one for added and one for modified.

```
private void TransfertToOriginal(simulation item)
    {


        try 
        {
        //Echeances that will be marked as deleted => found in "echeancier" 
        //and not in echeancierCopy

var EcheancesForDelete = item.echeancier.Except(item.echeancierCopy, new  EcheanceNumberComparer());

//Echeances that will be marked as modified => found in 2 collections
        var EcheancesForModify      = item.echeancier.Intersect(item.echeancierCopy,   new EcheanceNumberComparer());

//Echeances that will be marked as Added => found in "echeancierCopy" and not in "echeancier"
        var EcheancesForAdd         = item.echeancierCopy.Except(item.echeancier, new EcheanceNumberComparer());

//Beware to cast EcheancesForDelete collection To List otherwise an exception Collection was modified
foreach (Echeance ee in EcheancesForDelete.ToList())
        {
            base.GetCurrentUoW().Attach<Echeance>(ee);
            base.GetCurrentUoW().RegisterDeleted<Echeance>(ee);
        }

//Modification ....Don't forget ToList()
   foreach (Echeance ee in EcheancesForModify.ToList())
        {

            base.GetCurrentUoW().Attach<Echeance>(ee);
            base.GetCurrentUoW().RegisterChanged<Echeance>(ee);

        }


//New records here
        foreach (Echeance ee in EcheancesForAdd.ToList())
        {
            base.GetCurrentUoW().Attach<Echeance>(ee);
            base.GetCurrentUoW().RegisterNew<Echeance>(ee);
        }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


            _logger.LogException(ex);
            throw ex;
        }


    }
```

The comparer is as follows :

```
public class EcheanceNumberComparer : IEqualityComparer<Echeance>
{    
    public bool Equals(Echeance x, Echeance y)
    {

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;
        return x.EchNumber == y.EchNumber;
    }



    public int GetHashCode(Echeance e)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(e, null)) return 0;
        int hashEcheanceNumber = e.EchNumber.GetHashCode();
        return hashEcheanceNumber;
    }
}
```

Bye.